# Is it possible to generate a PNG directly rather than PDFs?

Tags: graphics

I mean there is `article`, `report`, `beamer`, `letter` ... but can I generate a picture ?

Something like : `\documentclass[]{image}`

Comment: You could generate a pdf and then convert to any format you want. Check the `standalone` package/class, which, if I remember correctly, has an `export` key.

Comment: Not directly, because you need the Imagemagick software, but you can use the `standalone` class with the `convert` option to convert the generated PDF into a PNG automatically. See the `convert` option in the documentation: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf

Comment: so it is half-possible :) can you please provide an example with `standalone` and `convert` as an answer please.

Comment: @darthbith `\documentclass[tikz,convert={outfile=phantom.svg}]{standalone}` ??

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in comment, we can use standalone conversion option, for example like this. (to generate phantom.png )

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={outfile=phantom.png}]{standalone}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{brain.png}};
 \draw [gray!60,fill=gray!60] (1,0) ellipse (5mm and 10mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy method to get a PNG file if you normally use a batch file to run LaTeX like I do (Windows version).  You will need to have `imagemagick` installed.

```
pdflatex sample.tex
pdflatex sample.tex
pdflatex sample.tex
pdfcrop sample.pdf sample_cropped.pdf
convert -density 150x150 sample_cropped.pdf sample_cropped.png
pause
```

This will result in a PDF *and* a cropped PNG file.  Leave out the call to `pdfcrop` if you don't want to crop the output PNG.  If you want the PDF *and* the PNG then this method saves you from altering the TeX file itself with the `standalone` package.

Comment: `convert` can auto trim the file by giving the option `-trim`.